# Bringing an Excel window to foreground from Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to open an Excel file from Access and it does work, however the Excel window pops up in the background (behind the Access window), which is not very user friendly. Here is the code I use:

```
Private Function OpenExcelAttachment()
Dim MyXL As Object
Set MyXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With MyXL

   Dim FullPath As String, Name As String
   Name = "\ExcelFile.xlsx"
   FullPath = CurrentProject.Path & Name
   .Workbooks.Open FullPath
   .Visible = True

 End With
```

How can I make the Excel window appear in the foreground (on top of all opened windows) instead?

Thank you!

Comment: It should be therefore there is no problem with your code. Programs only have a small amount of time to set themselves as a foreground window, is it a long time to loadfile? Try setting visible first then load file. `The system restricts which processes can set the foreground window. A process can set the foreground window only if one of the following conditions is true:`

Comment: `The process is the foreground process. The process was started by the foreground process. The process received the last input event. There is no foreground process. The foreground process is being debugged. The foreground is not locked (see LockSetForegroundWindow). The foreground lock time-out has expired (see SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT in SystemParametersInfo). Windows 2000/XP: No menus are active.`

Comment: Thank you for the reply! The file is small, so it doesn't take long at all. Playing around with when I set visible hasn't helped either. Interestingly, I found out that if I open VBA before calling Excel, it does show in the foreground! However if I quit Access, open it again and call Excel (which the potential user would do), it shows in the background...

Comment: Try Spy++ from MS programming languages tools folder or Windows SDK tools folder. See what is happening by logging all messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first check for already open instance of Excel. If you *must* allow for multiple instances of the Application, then it will be trickier.  If you are OK with only using one instance of Excel, then I think this should work using the [AppActivate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278643(v=office.15).aspx) statement.

```
Private Function OpenExcelAttachment()
Dim MyXL As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set MyXL = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then Set MyXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

With MyXL
   Dim FullPath As String, Name As String
   Name = "\ExcelFile.xlsx"
   FullPath = CurrentProject.Path & Name
   .Workbooks.Open FullPath
   .Visible = True
End With

AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It did work, however, as you have pointed out, requires a single Excel instance - something that cannot be guaranteed... Oh well, it's better than it was before anyway!

Answer (score 1):

AppActivate oWrkBk.Name & " - Excel"

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `AllowSetForegroundWindow` before making Excel visible. I don't develop in VBA, but I think it would look like this:

```vb
Private Declare Function AllowSetForegroundWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long
Private Function OpenExcelAttachment()
Dim MyXL As Object
Set MyXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
AllowSetForegroundWindow -1
With MyXL

   Dim FullPath As String, Name As String
   Name = "\ExcelFile.xlsx"
   FullPath = CurrentProject.Path & Name
   .Workbooks.Open FullPath
   .Visible = True
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party here,

(using Office 2013)

If Excel isn't already open, I find that:

```
.invisible = true
```

Brings the Excel window to the front if Excel isn't open. If Excel is already open however, I find I need to set invisible to false first then reset to true to get the window to the front

```
.invisible = false
.invisible = true
```

Maybe this should work?

```
Private Function OpenExcelAttachment()
Dim MyXL As Object
Set MyXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With MyXL

   Dim FullPath As String, Name As String
   Name = "\ExcelFile.xlsx"
   FullPath = CurrentProject.Path & Name
   .Workbooks.Open FullPath

   .Visible = False
   .Visible = True

 End With
```

EDIT:

Actually, what seems to work far better is AppActivate

```
AppActivate(nameOfExcelFile)
```

[AppActivate Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278643.aspx)